# spring data redis hash how to save null value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redis, spring-boot, spring-data

I need to save a User object to redis, and I am using hash. But some of fields in user object are `null` value.

My code like this:

```
public void saveObject(@PathVariable("userId") int userId){

    User user = this.userRepository.findOne(Long.valueOf(userId));

    HashMapper<User, String, String> hashMapper = new BeanUtilsHashMapper<User>(User.class);

    Map<String, String> userMap = hashMapper.toHash(user);

    String key = "USER_"+userId;
    this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash().putAll(key, userMap);
    //this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash().put(key, "id", String.valueOf(user.getId()));
    //this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash().put(key, "email", user.getEmail());


}
```

first, find User object from mysql by user id.

then, make User object to a hashmap, but some fields's value is `NULL`

third, using `putAll` method, store the map to redis.

```
this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash().putAll(key, userMap);
```

But some of my fields's value are null, I got the error: `NullPointerException`

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Below is tomcat exception log.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.sendCommand(Protocol.java:93) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.sendCommand(Protocol.java:78) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:101) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.hset(BinaryClient.java:229) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.hset(BinaryJedis.java:740) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.hSet(JedisConnection.java:2717) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.hSet(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:410) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations$9.doInRedis(DefaultHashOperations.java:172) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:191) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:86) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.put(DefaultHashOperations.java:169) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
at com.tradove.api.Redis.saveObject(Redis.java:124) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: would you mind opening an issue for [DATAREDIS](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS) preferably including a sample to reproduce the error.

Comment: already create the issue .https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-421

Comment: @diligent - Did you get solution to this issue ?

Comment: @PAA yes, just use the latest jar version

Comment: @diligent - Sorry I am not clear.. but what I come to know from other post that Spring Data Redis doesn't HASH the null values and hence values doesn't persists. If possible, please post your answer with the code. Thanks !